# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation distortes my image

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

My image is getting distorted when i am trying to rotate to 42 angle using following code.

```
diagonalImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(42 * M_PI / 180.0);
```

Please suggest me a solution.

I am getting the same problem in iPad Also.

Comment: you can take a look to this library also. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swimagerotation

Comment: distorted how? post some screen shots

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

[diagonalImageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90))];
```

hope it helps.